# How Do I Deploy An .Net MVC App with A Postgres Server to A Digital Ocean Droplet with A Github Action?

Tags: docker, devops, github-actions, digital-ocean, continuous-deployment

I have been hearing a lot about how I shouldn't deploy my apps manually. I deployed a static app recently from a Github Action to Netlify and it was incredibly convenient. The problem is that the new app I am deploying is a big Dynamic .Net MVC app that uses a Postgres db and has migrations. I have previously ran it from a Digital Ocean Droplet. I used to deploy it with the following steps:

### UFW Configure

> sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
> sudo ufw allow http
> sudo ufw allow https
> sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
> sudo ufw enable

### Certbot Setup

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx
> sudo service nginx restart
> sudo certbot --nginx -d MY-DOMAIN

### Setup Nginx for Dotnet

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

/etc/nginx/proxy.conf

```
roxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
```

### Prepare Db

> psql postgres
> CREATE DATABASE <db_name_here>;
> CREATE USER <user_name_here> WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD <password_here>;
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <db_name_here> TO <user_name_here>;

### App Build

> make sure the app has Postgres connection string
> dotnet restore
> dotnet ef database update
> dotnet publish --output ~/path/to/proj/dir/amaranth --configuration Release

### Deploy By Creating A Service

Create a service by creating this file at `/etc/systemd/system/amaranth.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=A .NET App running on Ubuntu

[Service]
#WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/
WorkingDirectory=/home/myusername/path/to/proj/dir/amaranth/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/myusername/path/to/proj/dir/amaranth/amaranth.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=myusername
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run `sudo systemctl start amaranth.service`

As you can see by reading the above this is a somewhat exhausting process. The first 3/4 steps **UFW Configure**, **Certbot Setup**, **Setup Nginx for Dotnet**, and possibly **Prepare Db** all only need to be run once and therefore don't need to be automated.

I would love to know of a way to automate the last 2 steps **App Build** and **Deploy By Creating A Service**, whether it be by making a Github action workflow or a docker file that completes these task for me.

Also just in general I'm looking for a simpler/safer way to deploy my .Net MVC app even if that means completely changing the deployment pipline. I would love if someone could explain to me the most efficient way to deploy a .Net MVC website with a Postgres database like my own on a Digital Ocean Droplet (or comparable linux server) in the most streamlined, least bug prone way. So how could I deploy this? Also, are there any obvious security vulnerabilities in this process or in any of my configuration files?